# Удалить элемент списка по клику на него

Tags: javascript

Необходимо удалить или изменить класс элемента li по клику на него. На чистом js  
Пример списка:
[image: Пример списка]

Comment: А вы знаете, что у вас смысл в заголовке и содержании различаются?

Comment: Так удалить или изменить CSS класс?

Comment: Простите, писал ночью уже ничего не соображал, надо было изменить класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с классами элементов (nodes) существует свойство [classList](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#klassy-v-vide-obekta-classlist) с доступными [методами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) для добавления, изменения, удаления классов элемента.

```js
// Выбираем все элементы с классом `.todo__link`,
// по которым будут выполняться щелчки.
const LINKS = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__link')

function toggleTodo(event) {
  // Отменяем действие по умолчанию.
  event.preventDefault()

  // Элемент по которому был выполнен щелчок.
  let target = event.target

  // Нас интересует родитель элемента с классом `li.todo`
  let item = target.closest('li.todo')

  // Если элемент найден, то:
  if (item) {
    // добавляем/удаляем класс у элемента `li.todo`.
    item.classList.toggle('done')
  }
}

// Добавляем ко всем ссылкам функцию обработчик для события `click`.
LINKS.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', toggleTodo)
})
```

```css
.todo__link {
  color: #08c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul class="todos">
  <li class="todo"><a href="#" class="todo__link">Задача #1</a></li>
  <li class="todo"><a href="#" class="todo__link">Задача #2</a></li>
  <li class="todo"><a href="#" class="todo__link">Задача #3</a></li>
  <li class="todo"><a href="#" class="todo__link">Задача #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Укороченный вариант решения:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.todo')
  .forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => item.classList.toggle('done'))
  })
```